# How to modify output buffer?

Tags: php, html, css, output, php-5.5

I'm trying to modify the contents of the output buffer.
I got something likes this:

```
if($this->page == 'login')
{
                $output = ob_get_contents();    // $output is index.html            
                //  have no idea how to modify `$output`
}
```

and my `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  </body>
     if($usr ==null) include 'login.php';
      else include main.php; //`main.php`  with header bar and footer bar
    // this's where i want to clean and insert my login form (login.php)
  </body>
</html>
```

and `login.php`:

```
<?php
  <form>
      .....
  </form>
?>
```

I have the `$output` but I want to clean all and insert the source of `login.php` into the body so that everyone could see my login form ( have `css` for  the style of website). I have searched on google and only know how to get the content, clean and flush. But I don't see how to modify the buffer contents. Is there a way to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of how the rest of your code works. But maybe you could use a tag to replace with. Something like this.

```
index.html
<html>
  <head></head>
  </body>
    {{body}}
  </body>
</html>


<?php
//Logic file
if($this->page == 'login')
{
    $output = ob_get_contents();    // $output is index.html 
    ob_clean();
    ob_start();
    include 'login.php';
    $login_content = ob_get_contents();    // $output is index.html  
    ob_clean();
    $content = str_replace('{{body}}', $login_content, $output);

    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: Actually, i did it in my index.php but  i think it's too poor code. So i tried ob_get_content in hope to modify the output.

Comment: That should work. Is your index.html being used as a template for all your pages? I've updated it to be {{body}}. You can use that to replace it with any content from your other pages.